# The type and namespace ------ could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

On my program i get the error message the type and namespace could not be found for ISaleManagerUI

I dont understand why it is not working and i don't know how to fix it. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

I do have a class called ISaleManagerUI.cs

This is the code below thank you

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.IO;
 using Antiques;
 using AntiqueSales;

namespace Antiques

{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page, ISaleMangerUI
{
    SaleList saleList;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, Session["ID"]))
            {
                Sale sale = new Sale((string)Session["ID"], (DateTime)Session["Date"], (string)Session["Location"], (double)Session["Picth Cost"], (int)Session["Capacity"],
                    (bool)Session["Yes"], (bool)Session["No"]), (string)Session["Charity"], (string)Session["Catering"];

                saleList = (SaleList)Application["SaleList"];

                saleList.addSale(sale);

                Application["SaleList"] = saleList;

                UpdateListbox();
            }
        }
        catch (DuplicateIdException)
        {
    //        UpdateListbox();
        }
        //lblError.Text = null;
    }
```

Comment: Does right clicking on `ISaleMangerUI` and selecting `Resolve` solve the issue ?

Comment: You might have an ISaleManagerUI, but I'm pretty sure the error you're getting is regarding the type or namespace ISaleMangerUI, with a missing letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant an "interface called ISaleManagerUI". I believe that all you have to is add a using directive. Try adding using "ISaleManagerUI's namespace".

Comment: I'm also assuming "ISaleMangerUI" is a typo that was posted on in the question vs. the actual code being used....if not I totally agree with neminem.